# Matrix Optimization on R

Tags: r

I have 2 matrices, an A(7*7), a target matrix(30*7) the target matrix is known.

I have a matrix A (7*7) which allows me to build a matrix B (30*7) in the following way:

1/ I take the last column of A, this column becomes the first row of my matrix B

2/ I take the squared of matrix A , the last column of A^2, this column becomes the second row of my matrix B

3/I take the cube of matrix A , the last column of A^3, this column becomes the third row of my matrix B

So on and on, in other words

The first line of B is  the last column of A

The 2nd row of B is  the last column of A^2

The 3rd row of B is  last column of A^3

So up to 30.

The resulting matrix B should be as close as possible to the target matrix! In other words I must find matrix A which after the succession of operations described above gives a matrix B similar to the target matrix.
How would you proceed?

Comment: Sorry i wasnt clear the B matrix and the target matrix are supposed to be the same ideally. The thing is that the matrix B is created with  while the target matrix is already Given.

Comment: We know the data in the target matrix, and we want to be able to recreate this matrix through the operations on the matrice A that i said above.

Comment: not really because i still dont know how to find the matrix A that will give me the target matrix after the operations  The main goal is to find A , the matrix A that give the target matrix after the operation

Comment: Ah, I totally missed the detail that you were trying to recreate A (even though you did say so in the text). Yes, my answer was not helpful; I'll delete it. Out of curiosity, do you have reason to believe that such a matrix A should exist at all? It's not in any way clear to me that it should, and if such a matrix *doesn't* exist, how would you like to define getting a result that is "close"?